# How do I get all sub-categories related to a category without the knowing how deep it goes.

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

This is a category table,

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is how you get Category and related Sub-Category.

```
SELECT root.name  AS root_name
     , down1.name AS down1_name
     , down2.name AS down2_name
  FROM categories AS root
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN categories AS down1
    ON down1.parentid = root.id
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN categories AS down2
    ON down2.parentid = down1.id

 WHERE root.parentid IS NULL
ORDER 
    BY root_name 
     , down1_name 
     , down2_name
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/835de/3)

What I have noticed is that this query goes only 2 step/nodes forward, like say

```
category > sub-category 1 > sub-category 2
```

What if I have a sub-category that goes beyond 2 step/nodes like say

```
category > sub-category 1 > sub-category 2 > sub-category 3
```

or even may be sub-category 4 do I need to add down3.name or down4.name to get to the end to include all sub-category or is there a better way?

Comment: You can't really in MySQL.  You have two choices:  change the representation of the hierarchy or use a recursive stored procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the complete hierarchy of an item using a recursive query.

ex:

```
    select c.id,c.name,@parent := c.parentid 
from 
 (select * from categories order by id desc) c
join 
 (select @parent := 16) t
where c.id =@parent
```

create a stored procedure to obtain the desired output for all item ids recursively.